# Reload from save() response with Ember-Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm currently using EmberJs along with Ember-Data to build an app backed by a Laravel JSON api.

I got a little issue on the saving process, mostly on model creation.

Here is my workflow :

1. The Ember ObjectController saves itself `this.get("model").save()`
2. Laravel (REST api) receives the data and persist it, therefore
   creating a unique ID for it
3. The api return the new data (that
   respect Ember convention) with the proper ID
4. ???? Ember-Data doesn't
   seems to care about the response since it does nothing...

The problem here : the `id` remains undefined even if it has been given...

The workaround I found is to reload models... but it's a big performance flaw considering that the data I want to be reloaded it available to Ember straight after the `save()`

any ideas ?

EDIT **

The problem only occurs on the first object that I add. When I repeat the process the next objects are refreshed correctly. If I hit refresh, it start again : the first object miss his refresh and the following are okay.

Here my code about the add process :

**route**

```
App.CategoriesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function()
    {
        return this.store.createRecord("category").set("active", true);
    },
    setupController: function(ctrl, model)
    {
        ctrl.set("errors", 0);
        ctrl.set("model", model);
    }
});
```

I don't have any Router for `CategoriesRoute` since the data is all in my ArrayController from the start.

**controller**

```
App.CategoriesNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: "application",
    actions:
    {
        save: function()
        {
            this.get("model").save();
            this.get("target").transitionTo("categories");    
        },
        cancel: function()
        {
            this.get("model").rollback();
            this.get("target").transitionTo("categories");
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT ** 2
I tried the code provided below with no success...

I added 2 records, and the first don't have it's ID... the second got it, so the problem appears to only be on the first save...

Here are the 2 responses I got from my API

ObjectA

```
{"category":{"nameFr":"aaa","nameEn":"aaa","active":true,"id":10}}
```

ObjectB

```
{"category":{"nameFr":"bbb","nameEn":"bbb","active":true,"id":11}}
```

Comment: Hmmm I haven't noticed this behavior. Are you using the latest beta version of Ember Data? If so, is the id not on the model or not on the controller (or not on either) after the model is saved? And could you post a bit of code or a JSBin to clarify what you're doing?

Comment: I added some details about the things I've found

Comment: What does the JSON object look like that you're returning to Ember?

Comment: Answer below, but there could be even more stuff going on. Could you add your CategoriesRoute code?

Comment: JSON looks fine. Maybe include a JSBin that has all your router code, as well as the code where you're accessing the id?

Comment: I'm viewing the thing in ember's debugger : http://i.imgur.com/T4dL91W.png

I can see it elsewhere in the code but basically, this is my point of reference

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you're transitioning before the save finishes, and so the model hook on the categories route fires while the model you're saving is still in flight (are you getting any errors in the console?). Try changing the save action to

```
    save: function()
    {
        var that = this;
        this.get("model").save().then(function(){
            that.get("target").transitionTo("categories");
        });
    },
```

Also, you don't need to `this.get('target')...` as there's a controller method `transitionToRoute`. You can simplify to:

```
    save: function()
    {
        var that = this;
        this.get("model").save().then(function(){
            that.transitionToRoute("categories");
        });
    },
```

Comment: Didn't work :( No I don't get any error down the console. Thanks though for the better syntax of transitioning

Answer (score 0):

Found that the problem seems to be on Ember-Data's side...

documented the whole thing here :

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/missing-id-on-first-save-on-a-new-object/4752